# FormGroup.valid iniciando como true IOINIC V3

Tags: typescript, formulário, ionic3

estou tentando validar um formulário que recebe apenas um parâmetro, nesse form tenho um botão buscar que só deve ser habilitado após ser digitado pelo menos 5 letras, porém está dando errado, pq o botão inicializa desbloqueado e quando começo a digitar ele bloqueia e desbloqueia novamente quando digito os 5 digitos, não uso muito o formGroup, então precisava saber pq ele está iniciando como "True".

Resumindo: o valid do form group deveria iniciar como false, mas está iniciando como true.

Minha TS:

```
this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
  nmFornecedor: ['', Validators.minLength(5)]
})
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Nome fornecedor</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="nmFornecedor"  ></ion-input>
  </ion-item> 

<button ion-button (click)="teste()" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">Resultado</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver este problema de uma maneira bem fácil, inserindo o atributo **`required`** no input, pode ver o exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-minlength):

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Nome fornecedor</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="nmFornecedor" required></ion-input>
  </ion-item> 

  <button ion-button (click)="teste()" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">Resultado</button>
</form>
```